# Got a problem in C++ Code with Compile Error

Tags: c++

I found Compile Error.
Actually, It works. but I submitted this code to the site for assignment.
and a site warned me that you have a problem which says
"no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Product’ and ‘’)"
How could I solve this error?
and where should I fix code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Product {
    char name[3][6];
    int price[3];
};

int main() {

    Product A, B, C;
    char ch;
    int sum = 0;
    int average;
    
    A = { "strawberry", "melon", "watermelon", 300, 500, 1000 };
    B = { "strawberry", "melon", "watermelon", 450, 450, 900 };
    C = { "strawberry", "melon", "watermelon", 200, 150, 700 };

    cin >> ch;

    if (ch == 'A') {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            sum += A.price[i];
        }
    }
    else if (ch == 'B') {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            sum += B.price[i];
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            sum += C.price[i];
        }
    }

    average = sum / 3;

    cout << average;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you plan to store "strawberry" and "watermelon" in a char array of size 6?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If your code compiles and runs without error, then you have no problem. If a robot still dislikes it, then that's the robot's problem.

Comment: You missing every array-syntax initializer in your assignments, and in case you forgot to count, strawberry and watermelon have a lot more than 5 characters. [see here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7308c308482739e).

Comment: `char name[3][6];` --> `std::string name[3];`

Comment: May I ask why *a* product has *three* names and *three* prices? Are you sure that this is what you are required to do?

Comment: when you submit your code somewhere you need to find out what compiler they are using and what compiler options, otherwise submitting is a matter of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalid initialization of structures. You have to initialize, at the time of its declaration.

```
  Product  A = { {"strawberry", "melon", "watermelon"}, {300, 500, 1000}};
  Product  B = { {"strawberry", "melon", "watermelon"}, {450, 450, 900 }};
  Product  C = { {"strawberry", "melon", "watermelon"}, {200, 150, 700 }};
```

And the column size of `name` should be increased.
Change `char name[3][6];`  to `char name[3][20];`

Comment: Thanks for answering! this finally works without erorr! really so much thank you!

Comment: Actually, it may surprise you to learn that [eliding the braces is valid](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9f045f0479e82f5)! _([ref](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#15))_

Comment: You're right that it needs to be an _initialisation_, though.

Comment: @Sylla This answer does not explain the nature of the error. If to enlarge the size of elements of the character array the code should compile. It seems it is a bug of the compiler or some peculiarity of the C++ 14 Standard. So the answer is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @Sylla The reason of the error is that it seems the compiler converts string literals in the initializer list to pointers to them. It  shall not do that. So it is unable to initialize the character array with pointers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Are you sure? the error emitted by gcc is `no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Product' and '<brace-enclosed initializer list>')` and it disappears when the aggregate s initialized like in this answer.

Comment: @Bob__ The error does not have a relation to the initialization in the declaration The error have a relation to building of an object of the type Product from the initializer list. that will be assigned to an already existed object of the type Declare the structure without the character array and the assignment will work.

Comment: @Bob__ For example this program compiles successfully using a compiler that supports the C++_14 Standard. #include <iostream>

struct Product {
    int name[3][3];
    int price[3];
};

int main() 
{
 Product A = { 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 300, 500, 1000 };
 
 A = { 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 300, 500, 1000 };
 

 return 0;
}. So the answer to the question does not make a sense.

Comment: @Bob__ Try this program at www.ideone.com selecting the tag C++14.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It doesn't seem to be a matter of C++14 compliancy. It doesn't work on gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/YxGq7T

Comment: @Bob__ The program I showed compiles successfully, And moreover the program in the question is also compiled successfully by MS VS 2019. So in any case the answer shall explain the reason why the code is not compiled by one compiler and  is compiled by another compiler. So the answer is totally irrelevant to the question.